# limit of a sequence based on another sequence

Tags: limits

I am given a sequence whose limit, as n approaches infinity is 1. I want to calculate the limit of another sequence based off that.

The given sequence is:
$\lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{n!}{n^n e^{-n} \sqrt{2\pi n}}) = 1$

The limit I want to find is for the following sequence:
$\lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{(2n)!\sqrt{n}}{(n!)^2 4^n}) $

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put
$$
a_n := \frac{n!}{n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}}
\quad\text{and}\quad
b_n := \frac{(2n)!\sqrt{n}}{4^n(n!)^2}
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
a_{2n} = \frac{(2n)!}{2(2n)^{2n}e^{-2n}\sqrt{\pi n}} = \ldots = \frac{(2n)!\sqrt{n}}{4^n(n!)^2}\cdot\frac{(n!)^2}{2n^{2n+1}e^{-2n}\sqrt{\pi}} = b_n\cdot a_n^2\sqrt\pi.
\end{align*}
Letting $n\to\infty$ gives $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n = \frac 1{\sqrt\pi}$.